# Fake Links Showing up in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, links, web-crawlers

Google Webmaster tools is reporting a large increase in 'not found errors' on my site, and I see approximately 1700 'Not Found Errors over the past 2 months. All of them are for a url that is formatted like:

```
http://mydomain.com/click.php?c%3EdHm7fnGkc3Smdz6kc31%3E'dmjdlgsbve%3E2'lfzxpset%3EQfbs'sbol%3E2'f%3Evt%3Cvt%3C79%3C2%3C2%3C54528243%3Cgmbnjohpspbe%3C2%3C6224'vsm%3Eiuuq%264B%263G%263Gxxx%2Fopdmjdlz%2Fdpn%263G'gffe%3Eopqbz'qsjdf%3E'tbq%3E%3A84%3A9g54e662db639%3A28eeb2cc8bb8e9'zbsht%3Exxx%2Fopdmjdlz%2Fdpn
```

Google says these are linked from:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php?Keywords=Pear&search_type=related2&cat2=Lemon+Cake&r=c%3EdHm7fnGkc3Smdz6kc31%3E'f%3Evt%3Cvt%3C79%3C2%3C2%3C27748763%3Ctuzmf2%60dvtupn/dtt%3C3%3Cjoufsdptnpt%60bggjmjbuf%603%60e3s%60efsq%3Cgmbnjohpspbe%3Cgmbnjohpspbe%3C656178%3C6224%3Cdmfbo%3Cmjtujoht%3Czbipp%3C'jqvb%60je%3E:84:9g54e662db639:28eeb2cc8bb8e9'enybsht%3Eg4dc139e6673d:812b:b::d8e34:9fe9&rd=1
```

When I browse to the url Google says these are linked from (both using my browser, and the fetch by Google tool), I don't see any links on the page to click.php. These links are supposedly coming from MY domain / server, but click.php does not even exist on my server. When I look through my server logs, I do not see any of the index.php? urls this says they are accessed from.

What am I missing here? Is the link getting encoded in the url or something? How can I fix this? I would REALLY appreciate some help in figuring this out.

**Update:**

I had purchased a domain (that was previously parked), and moved my site to it a few months ago. Apparently these links existed on the parked domain, and Google has gone through and crawled all ~1700 of the links twice now. Once a few months ago, and once 2 days ago. Is this something that will affect my ranking in Google? Is there any way to notify Google that all of these links are gone / incorrect? Should I use the 'remove urls' tool in webmaster tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***These links are supposedly coming from MY domain / server, but click.php does not even exist on my server.***

This sounds like a server or web application [exploit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_%28computer_security%29). You should likely run a virus check and a [web application security scanner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_security_scanner).

You should also configure your web server to return a [410 Gone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) error for any requests containing *click.php* (or pattern only found in the bogus URLs):

> **410 Gone** Indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will not be available again. This should be used when
>   a resource has been intentionally removed and the resource should be
>   purged. Upon receiving a 410 status code, the client should not
>   request the resource again in the future. Clients such as search
>   engines should remove the resource from their indices. Most use cases
>   do not require clients and search engines to purge the resource, and a
>   "404 Not Found" may be used instead.

Comment: That was my thought at first too, but it seems odd that the click.php link does not show up for me when using fetching via the Googlebot useragent. I can send a url if that would help. In the meantime, I'm running nikto, and looking for other tools.

Comment: Side note: I've been looking into this for a few days now, and have come up with nothing. The fact that I can't reproduce the link makes this a lot more challenging.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Answer post below.

Comment: Apparently I can't answer this (I have too few reputation points), so I selected this as the answer, and put the answer in the main post. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll add it as an "Update" to the question. The 410 Gone server response still applies. You can use the [Disavow links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) tool, however Google will remove them after it receives the 410 response for them anyway.

Comment: Do I disavow the links even though they are coming from my domain? Index.php is a valid url on my site, just the links (click.php) that previously existed for this url are not valid, and should be removed. Googlebot doesn't crawl the index.php?Keywords=... pages, it has just been crawling the page that this previously linked to.

Comment: As indicated, you should configure your server to return a 410 Gone error for URLs containing "click.php" - you can use the disavow tool for these URLs too, however Google should remove them the next time it attempts to crawl them and receives the 410 error.

Answer (score 0):

Disallow those URL using Robots.txt. As these fake URL must have been created during development process and are indexed as well.

Comment: Do I disavow the links even though they are coming from my domain? Index.php is a valid url on my site, just the links (click.php) that previously existed for this url are not valid, and should be removed. Googlebot doesn't crawl the index.php?Keywords=... pages, it has just been crawling the page that this previously linked to.